# Diffrence between PLOCAL and REMOTE while creating database in orient DB?

Tags: orientdb, database, nosql

Am using OrientDB database in this I am creating database using command `create database PLOCAL:path/testdb  admin admin PLOCAL DOCUMENT` document type database , and I have created two classes **comment** and **post** which having properties postId in comment class and Id in post class. Then am trying to create link between these two classes.using command `create LINK Usercomments TYPE LINKSET FROM comment.postId TO post.Id`.
This command showing error `"Error on execution of command: sql.create LINK comments TYPE LINKSET FROM comment.postId TO post.Id, java.util.UnknownFormatConversionException: Conversion = '%'"`. Same case is working if i create database using command `create database remote:localhost/testdb  admin admin memory DOCUMENT`. What is the difference between **PLOCAL** and **REMOTE** while creating Database?

Comment: Hi Sunil, which OrientDB version are you using ?

Comment: Hi LucaS, Am using orientdb-community-2.1.12 version.

Comment: explained in the documentation : https://orientdb.com/docs/3.0.x/datamodeling/Concepts.html#database-url

Answer (score 2):

According to the [OrientDB official docs](http://orientdb.com/docs/2.1/Console-Command-Create-Database.html), `PLOCAL` and `REMOTE` in the `<database-url> <mode>` argument specifies the type of the connection you're using to connect to the created db and it's different from `<storage-type>` argument which specifies the type of the storage that you want to use :

- **PLOCAL**: If you create a DB in this way, you automatically connect to it in `PLOCAL` mode. It uses a disk based storage to ensure data persistence. E.g.:

  ```
  create database plocal:/path/to/db/dbname document

  Creating database [plocal:/path/to/db/dbname] using the storage type [plocal]...
  Database created successfully.
  ```
- **REMOTE**: If you create a database by using REMOTE mode, you have to specify the storage type which can be `PLOCAL` or `MEMORY`. E.g.:

  - **PLOCAL**: it uses a disk based storage.

    ```
    create database remote:localhost/dbname root root plocal

    Creating database [remote:localhost/dbname] using the storage type [plocal]...
    Connecting to database [remote:localhost/dbname] with user 'admin'...OK
    Database created successfully.
    ```
  - **MEMORY**: It uses the volatile memory to create and save the db. It doesn't assure the data persistance and you'll lose all data when you restart the machine. E.g.:

    ```
    orientdb {db=dbname}> create database remote:localhost/dbname1 root root memory

    Creating database [remote:localhost/dbname1] using the storage type [memory]...
    Connecting to database [remote:localhost/dbname1] with user 'admin'...OK
    Database created successfully.
    ```

Hope it helps

Comment: I agree to the points u told. Why if I create database in PLOCAL mode, am unable to create link between two classes post and comment. As I mentioned in my question. And how it is able to create link between classes, if I create database in REMOTE mode. Thankyou.

Comment: Hi Sunil, how did you declare the classes properties ?

Comment: ,create property post.Id Integer
create property comment.postId Integer,
create LINK Usercomments TYPE LINKSET FROM comment.postId TO post.Id

I have used all these commands to create property and to create link between comment and post

Comment: 1.create property post.Id Integer.
2.create property comment.postId Integer.
3.create LINK Usercomments TYPE LINKSET FROM comment.postId TO post.Id.

I have used all these commands to create property and to create link between comment and post

Comment: Hi Sunil, I found [this](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/orient-database/tKCO5JrCT-s) problem on the Orient Google Community and it seems similar to yours. I hope you'll find it useful.